# How to reference to an ID of another model definition in Swagger

Tags: json, rest, swagger

Let's assume I have a User and a UserType model. I would like to add a reference to the UserType-ID in the User model. The swagger documentation only shows how to reference to another (whole) model, not just to one of it's properties.

So I was wondering it it's even possible to reference only to a property of another model definition.

```
"definitions": {
    "User": {
        "required": [
            "username",
            "typeId"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "username": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "typeId": {
                "$ref": "UserType.id" // ==> this doesn't work! and without
                                      // the ".id" part it would include all
                                      // the properties of UserType
            }
        }
    },
    "UserType": {
        "required": [
            "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or is that not possible at all and it should always be just:

```
"definitions": {
    "User": {
        ...
        "properties": {
            "typeId": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Before I go into the answer, why do you want to reference a *primitive* definition? What does that save you in writing?

Comment: I guess I think it would be clearer for anybody reading the REST documentation to see the "linked" Model.

Comment: And in case I would need to change the type of UserType.id I wouldn't need to update all the references.

Comment: In the purest sense, referencing from one object to another does not mean a relation between the objects. It's just copying definition. I would suggest explaining by "description" and not that way. As for the second comment, I can show you how to do that - that use case makes more sense. However, if that's what you want, I'd ask that you edit the question first to clarify it.

Comment: something like `"$ref": "#/definitions/UserType/properties/id"`?

Comment: Technically, yes, but I cannot guarantee we'd actually support it. This is not what we intended and we may need to clarify it. I'd suggest externalizing the typeId altogether.

Comment: can you give an example? (as an answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Swagger 2.0, Schema Objects don't necessary describe models (unlike the Model Object in previous versions). For example, if you look at "body" parameters, you'll see you need to define a Schema as the type, but that schema can also represent primitives and arrays.

For the question above (and comments), I'd suggest using the following structure:

```
"defintions": {
  "User": {
    "required": [
      "username",
      "typeId"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      },
      "username": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "typeId": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeId"
      }
    }
  },
  "UserType": {
    "required": [
      "name"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/TypeId"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "TypeId": {
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "int32"
  }
}
```

The TypeId is now externalized, and should the time come and you want to change its definition, you can change it in one place. Of course, you may want to add additional `"description"` to the fields and models to better document the purpose of the.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way to go currently. Sadly it loses some data that could be useful for generating a database based on the schema.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. This is an API documentation tool and not an application/database one. Projecting from an API representation to a database representation is more often than not fundamentally wrong.

Comment: is this still holds valid?

Comment: Is what still holds valid?